# Getting data out of object variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, mediawiki-api

when i execute this function

```js
const stronaDyskusji = "Some_mediawiki_discussion_page_name";

async function sekcje() {
    var zwrot;
    const params = {
        action: "parse",
        page: stronaDyskusji,
        prop: "sections",
    };
    const api = new mw.Api();

    await api.get(params).done((data) => {
        zwrot = data.parse["sections"];
    });
    return zwrot;
}


var PIT = sekcje()
console.log(PIT)
```

the console logs [this kind of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV5h2.png).
Is there any way to get this array out of this `[[PromiseResoult]]:` to for example other variable?

Comment: An  `async` function always returns a promise. You either call `.then(...)` on that promise or use `await` to "get the data out".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get data from async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438910/get-data-from-async-function)

Comment: @FelixKling i have this data inside variable PIT so you recomend me to use `.then(...)` on this variable?

Comment: @FelixKling the second method worked thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async functions return promise. If you want to access the result directly you will need to either use await (when you make the sekcje function call) or use the "then" callback on the returned promise.

```
const PIT = await sekcje();
console.log(PIT);
```

But for the await to work you will need to put it inside an async function.

Comment: That is something i've been looking for this snippet is inside whole long async function so it works great.